# java error(j2me)

Tags: java-me

```
Starting emulator in execution mode
Installing suite from: http://127.0.0.1:49874/rtspd.jad
[WARN] [rms     ] javacall_file_open: _wopen failed for: C:\Users\Ishan\javame-sdk\3.0\work\0\appdb\_delete_notify.dat

[WARN] [rms     ] javacall_file_open: _wopen failed for: C:\Users\Ishan\javame-sdk\3.0\work\0\appdb\_ch_suite.raw

[WARN] [rms     ] javacall_file_open: _wopen failed for: C:\Users\Ishan\javame-sdk\3.0\work\0\appdb\_ch_single.raw

[WARN] [rms     ] javacall_file_open: _wopen failed for: C:\Users\Ishan\javame-sdk\3.0\work\0\appdb\_ch_single.raw

[WARN] [rms     ] javacall_file_open: _wopen failed for: C:\Users\Ishan\javame-sdk\3.0\work\0\appdb\_ch_single.raw

[WARN] [rms     ] javacall_file_open: _wopen failed for: C:\Users\Ishan\javame-sdk\3.0\work\0\appdb\_ch_single.raw
```

what is this error about?am i missing any files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly looks like some files were brutally deleted even though either a MIDlet or the emulator still depends on them. Alternatively, the emulator could be trying to open the files for exclusive use while they are still locked by another process. Maybe a previous instance of the emulator that didn't properly close or some background process searching your hard drive.